# What does _REV suffix mean in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

Reading through OpenGL reference manual for [glVertexAttribPointer](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml) I've found it accepts a pretty weird `type` value (actually two of them):

> Additionally (...), **GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV**, and **GL_UNSIGNED_INT_2_10_10_10_REV** are accepted by `glVertexAttribPointer`

What does `_REV` suffix mean here?

Comment: That's actually a duplicate of [that question from GD.se](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46304/using-gl-int-2-10-10-10-rev-in-glvertexattribpointer) (which obviously didn't get enough attention).

Comment: Also I've been able to find that for color components, `_REV` means that "component packing order is reversed", though I wasn't able to find that does that exactly mean, especially for vertex attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A part of explanation found on : http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2033340&seqNum=3
Section Packed Data

> **Packed Data Formats for Vertex Attributes**
>
> Going back to the glVertexAttribPointer() command, you will notice that the allowed values for the size parameter are 1, 2, 3, 4, and the special token GL_BGRA. Also, the type parameter may take one of the special values GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV or GL_UNSIGNED_INT_2_10_10_10_REV, both of which correspond to the GLuint data type. These special tokens are used to represent packed data that can be consumed by OpenGL. The GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV and GL_UNSIGNED_INT_2_10_10_10_REV tokens represent four-component data represented as ten bits for each of the first three components and two for the last, packed in reverse order into a single 32-bit quantity (a GLuint). GL_BGRA could just have easily been called GL_ZYXW.5 Looking at the data layout within the 32-bit word, you would see the bits divided up as shown in Figure 3.3.
>
> Figure 3.3:
>
> [image]
>
> In Figure 3.3, the elements of the vertex are packed into a single 32-bit integer in the order w, x, y, z—which when reversed is z, y, x, w, or b, g, r, a when using color conventions. In Figure 3.4, the coordinates are packed in the order w, z, y, x, which reversed and written in color conventions is r, g, b, a.
>
> Figure 3.4
>   [image]
>
> Figure 3.4. Packing of elements in a RGBA-packed vertex attribute
>
> Vertex data may be specified only in the first of these two formats by using the GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV or GL_UNSIGNED_INT_2_10_10_10_REV tokens. When one of these tokens is used as the type parameter to glVertexAttribPointer(), each vertex consumes one 32-bit word in the vertex array. The word is unpacked into its components and then optionally normalized (depending on the value of the normalize parameter before being loaded into the appropriate vertex attribute. This data arrangement is particularly well suited to normals or other types of attributes that can benefit from the additional precision afforded by the 10-bit components but perhaps don’t require the full precision offered by half-float data (which would take 16-bits per component). This allows the conservation of memory space and bandwidth, which helps improve performance.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That image alone is confusing, because it only applies when using `GL_BGRA` as number of components and not for the usual order, unfortunately it isn't from you either but still destroys the value of the answer somehow.

Comment: @ChristianRau "Vertex data may be specified only in the first of these two formats" (in the article) would suggest it's the only possible combination anyway.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz *"Vertex data may be specified only in the first of these two formats"* - Huh, where did you read that from?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I'm not sure what this strange link from this answer is actually saying, but the specification as well as the documentation you linked to in the question definitely say that you can very well use a size of `4` (and thus standard `RGBA` ordering) with those packed formats.